# Pannellum dragHandleFunction

Tags: drag, pannellum

I am using this new feature of draggable hotspot in Pannellum :

```
var dragHandler = function (e) {
        console.log(e)
 }

"hotSpots": [
                {

                    "pitch": 5,
                    "yaw": 11,
                    "type": "info",
                     draggable:true,
                     "dragHandleFunc": dragHandler
                },
```

Dragging works fine but I cannot get dragHandler to be called. I am using the latest plugin files available on github.

Comment: Where did you find that feature?, I could not find documentation about that feature

Comment: I am not sure what is the current release but this was part of their code last time I checked, just undocumented yet.